# Why am I receiving a stack overflow?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

My first block of code is my Item Object file; the second is the Main Class. Before there was not any issues with the code running but after I had added a read and write file my code had started to receive a stack flow error.  just the snippet of which the error is being called.

```
    public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static String name;
    public static double price;
    public static double amount;
    public int max = 1;
    SlayerProgram sp = new SlayerProgram();
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
    public Item(String name, double price,double amount )
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.amount = amount;

    }

    public void ItemSet(String name, double price,double amount)
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.amount = amount  
    }
```

My Main class:

```
    public class SlayerProgram {
//import file txts, and Item Class

        static String name;
        static double price;
        static double amount;
 Item item = new Item(name,price,amount);
ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
static String fileNameText = "D:\\Game\\SlayerProgram\\Name.txt";
static String filePriceInt = "D:\\Game\\SlayerProgram\\Price.txt";
static String fileAmountInt ="D:\\Game\\SlayerProgram\\Amount.txt";

   //begin file Read   

public void BeginText() throws IOException
{
    TextFile();
}

public void Max()
{
    item.Max();
}

    //declare needed Data Types;
        final int max = item.max;
        ArrayList<String> Name  = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> Price = new ArrayList<>();
        double size = Price.size();
        ArrayList<Double> Amount = new ArrayList<>();


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at slayerprogram.Item.<init>(Item.java:18)
at slayerprogram.SlayerProgram.<init>(SlayerProgram.java:25)
at slayerprogram.Item.<init>(Item.java:18)
at slayerprogram.SlayerProgram.<init>(SlayerProgram.java:25)
```

How can I find where the stack overflow is being caused?

Comment: Would you mind correctly formatting your code? It will be easier to read and help others to quickly scan your code for errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Item` creates `SlayerProgram`:

```
SlayerProgram sp = new SlayerProgram();
```

And `SlayerProgram` creates `Item`

```
Item item = new Item(name,price,amount);
```

And therefore on initialization you will create those objects endlessly

There's a similar [Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-overflow-error) for getting StackOverflowError

> This ends up with a StackOverflowError since the constructor of ClassOne is instantiating ClassTwo, and the constructor of ClassTwo again is instantiating ClassOne.

Comment: Aka _ill-founded mutual recursion_

Comment: @Marco Thanks, Do you have a reference link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a `circular` dependency between `Item` and `SlayerProgram` class. You have created `Item item = new Item(name,price,amount);` in class `SlayerProgram` and `SlayerProgram sp = new SlayerProgram();` in class `Item`. So when you try to create the object of `Item` it will try to create the object of `SlayerProgram` and then `SlayerProgram` try to create the object of `Item` and it goes on still the `method stack is not full` and leads to `StackOverflow`.